# mysqldb python winserver metadata error

Tags: windows, module, mysql-python, plesk

I'm trying to install the mysqldb modul for python2.7 on my Windows vserver.
So i run the setup.py of mysqldb in cmd and get an error - called "No Sectoin: 'metadata'".

So i thought it could be a path problem. Because on my Server plesk is installed. And MySQL is installed in Plesk, the path to MySQL isnt normal: "C:\Parallels\Plesk\Databases\MySQL51", 
my question is how can i tell the module that MySQL is installed there and would this fix the error?

sry for my bad english and thanks for answers!

geetz wayne

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to edit `site.cfg` and fix the registry setting there, but since you have posted this, there is a [Windows MSI package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/latest/download) on SourceForge that should solve your problem. The SVN version (soon to be 1.2.4) skips using the registry and will be a bit easier to build on Windows.